# Jquery, onclick, get this img src by using this

Tags: jquery

I'm a rookie to jquery and javascript, all I want to do is to get the src of the image with a onclick event mouse. I already have a function (which is openPicture()), so is there any kind of easy way to put src img inside a variable in my function? Like, is there a openPicture(this.src) or somethin like that? This is what I tried and it doesn't worked :

```
var srcPicture = $(this).prop('src');
```

My html :

```
<div id="mainPicture">
    <img src="/upload/inventaire/<?= $result->user_id; ?>/<?= $mainPicture; ?>" alt="Picture Car" onclick="openPicture(this.src);">
</div>
<div id="secondPictures">
    <div class="containerPicture"><img src="/upload/inventaire/<?= $result->user_id; ?>/<?= $picture[1]; ?>" alt="car picture list1" onclick="openPicture();" <?= $user->imageErreur(); ?>></div>
    <div class="containerPicture"><img src="/upload/inventaire/<?= $result->user_id; ?>/<?= $picture[2]; ?>" alt="car picture list2" <?= $user->imageErreur(); ?>></div>
    <div class="containerPicture"><img src="/upload/inventaire/<?= $result->user_id; ?>/<?= $picture[3]; ?>" alt="car picture list3" <?= $user->imageErreur(); ?>></div>
</div>
```

Comment: You've answered your own question, why don't you try `openPicture(this.src)`? As a sidenote, jQuery has easy to use event handlers so you don't have to use inline javascript from 1998.

Comment: You must fire `click` event after `ready` event. Also use `attr` instead of `prop` [if jquery version > 1.7 ]

Comment: what do you mean by javascript from 1998, lol?

Answer (score 0):

Like @adeneo said, you just have to create function that takes src of image as an argument, like this:

```
var showImage = function(src) {
    $('#some_elem_id').after("<img src='" + src + "'/>");
}
```